# How to prove that $Q_8$ is not subgroup of $S_4$ by using Sylow theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

**Prove that $Q_8$ is not subgroup of $S_4$.**

It is trivial that $D_4$ is a subgroup of $S_4$.

But the case $Q_8$ make me confuse why this group is not a subgroup of the $S_4$.

Why $Q_8$ isn't a subgroup of $S_4$ ?

Many people might proved those statement either Group action or using mapping.

But I want to know prove those statement using Sylow theorem.

PS How many $P_2$ (Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_4$ whose order is 8) are in $S_4$?

Comment: By Sylow's theorem, all Sylow 2-subgroups are conjugate, so they are isomorphic to $D_4$.

Comment: Ah ha! Let the $Q_8$ is a subgroup of $S_4$, then $Q_8$ is a sylow 2 group. But since $Q_8$ and $S_4$ are not isomorphic, it's contradiction. Is my guess right?

Comment: That should be: since $Q_8$ and $D_4$ are not isomorphic!

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By $D_n$ I assume you mean the dihedral group of order $2n$.

Note that a Sylow-2 of $S_4$ has order $8$, so we know $D_4$ is a Sylow-2 of $S_4$.  Since any two Sylow-$p$ are conjugate, they are isomorphic.  Thus all subgroups of order $8$ in $S_4$ have to be isomorphic to $D_4$.

Note that $n_2\equiv 1\pmod{2}$, $n_2\mid \#S_4$, so either $n_2=1$ or $n_2=3$.  But the number of 4-cycles in $S_4$ is 6, and an $D_4$ only has two element of order 4.  Since any group of order 4 appears as a subgroup of a Sylow-2, we cannot have $n_2=1$ and hence $n_2=3$.

Comment: You meant there are some elements in $S_4$(not in $D_4$) Whose order is 4. So $n_2$ is 3. Am I right?